# 2-way databinding with ObservableField<>, set() doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a parent class, lets call it *BaseViewModel*, this class can be typed and have an *ObservableField* of the same type. Like this :

```
public class BaseViewModel<T> extends BaseObservable {

    ObservableField<T> value = new ObservableField<>();

    public T getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value.set(value);
        setHasChanges(value != originalValue);
    }

}
```

I got many child for this class. One of them is *StringViewModel* that, like its name says, gives a String value. This child class overrides the *setValue()* method :

```
public class StringViewModel extends BaseViewModel<String> {

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value.set(value);
        if(value != null && !value.isEmpty()){
            setHasChanges(!value.equals(originalValue));
        }
        else if(originalValue == null)
            setHasChanges(false);
        else
            setHasChanges(!originalValue.isEmpty());
    }

    //Other methods ...

}
```

And I got a layout that use a *StringViewModel* :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.myproject.viewmodels.StringViewModel" />

    </data>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:clickable="@{viewModel.editable}"
        android:cursorVisible="@{viewModel.editable}"

        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:focusable="@{viewModel.editable}"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="@{viewModel.editable}"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"

        android:text="@={viewModel.value}"
        app:setError="@{viewModel.error}"

        tools:text="Dupont" />

    <!-- Other layouts ... -->
```

But when I call the ***setValue()*** method of my *StringViewModel*, the value is set to the ViewModel but not on the *EditText*.

Edit : I should also say that I've add my *StringViewModel* to my *DataBinding* correctly (using *DataBindingUtil* to inflate my DataBinding).

`myDataBinding.setViewModel(new StringViewModel());`

Does someone got an explanation to this behavior?

---

***EDIT***

As @iMDroid said, I should have call `notifyChange()` in my method `setValue()`. I tought *ObservableFields* was doing it for me, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not expert in two-way data binding.. but I have been reading articles about it so here is one solution which might help you.

Suppose your model class is this:

```
public class Echo {
  public String text;
}
```

And your layout file is `R.layout.echo`

> They say you are supposed to set the layout using the
>   **DataBindingUtil** class and then the object on which you make the binding that is EchoBinding (automatically generated
>   according to the layout) like this:

```
 EchoBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
      this, R.layout.echo);
    binding.setEcho(new Echo());
```

Also, you can bind the value to your EditText using `app:binding="@{echo.text}"` attribute.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width=”match_parent”
  android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
  android:hint="Text 1"
  app:binding="@{echo.text}"/>
```

And lastly add `notifyChange()` to your `setValue()` method.

Refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761#.3dme0bkcq) for more information.

You may give it a try.. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help but as I edited my question I forgot to mention this point. I actually had correctly add my variable to the DataBinding using DataBindingUtil.

Comment: Even I have edited my answer.. did you try adding notifyChange()?

Comment: Nice it's working ! I thought because it was ObservableField I didn't have to notify anything, my bad. Thank's for the help, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the StringViewModel to the layout is not enough. In the onCreate() or onCreateView() depending on which you are using(Activity or Fragment), you have to tell your dataBinding to use the defined StringViewModel class.

in onCreate(), you want to do something like,

dataBinding.viewModel = new StringViewModel();

now, the dataBinding knows what you mean and they are now connected.

I believe you have setup the dataBinding.

Comment: Yes I set the StringViewModel to my DataBinding. Sorry I will update my question to add this information.